# Есть ли в elastic search возможность посмотреть по каким ключевым словам он нашел данные по запросу?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic

Хотелось бы получать в ответе слова по которым нашлись совпадения, для того, чтобы посмотреть какое предложение я отправил в начале и как анализатор мог разобрать его на токены и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

В запрос можно добавить **"explain": true**, и тогда в ответе придет немного подробностей, как и что он нашел, в основном полезно когда у тебя несколько критериев поиска.

Так же в **Index API** есть **analyze** - туда можно сделать запрос указав анализатор, текст, фильтры и в ответ получить что анализатор делает с запросом, подробности тут https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html